# InvalidArchiveError when executing conda install notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, conda, miniconda

I have conda 4.8.1 running on windows 10 enterprise edition and it is showing me following error whenever I try to install notebook.

`InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive D:\\Miniconda3\\pkgs\\notebook-6.0.2-py37_0ujelie94\\pkg-notebook-6.0.2-py37_0.tar.zst.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCan't create '\\\\?\\D:\\Miniconda3\\pkgs\\notebook-6.0.2-py37_0\\Lib\\site-packages\\notebook\\static\\components\\MathJax\\extensions\\a11y\\invalid_keypress.mp3'")`

I have tried different versions of notebook and reinstalled anaconda and miniconda many times. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: are you trying to update through the command line on Anaconda or the Anaconda Navigator?  I just tried through the Navigator and it came back to tell me that I cannot install on the environment but then asked if I wanted to install as a new environment.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04, I used `conda clean -a` and then it works perfectly.
Actually what `conda clean -a` does is cleaning the compressed .bz files and deleting older versions of package folders and does nothing to the new ones.

P.S.:  Make sure you installed Anaconda or Miniconda into a directory that contains only 7-bit ASCII characters and no spaces, such as C:\anaconda!

Comment: Works exactly the same way on windows, I had a similar problem and your solution solved it.

Comment: I had this problem on Ubuntu 16.04. `conda clean -a` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using pip worked. It downloaded the correct version of TensorFlow (2.16.3), which is compatible with Python 3.9.18. I had TensorFlow 2.10.0, which was giving the InvalidArchiveError.

```bash
pip install tensorflow
```