# Conda Create Environment Error: InternalArchiveError

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

first time posting on stackoverflow.
So I guess to summarize my problem I should say that I want to do some work with Python's statsmodels. However statsmodels only supports up to Python 3.8 and I am using 3.9. So I need to create a new conda environment. After that I will need to set it up in Spyder.

Um..I am using Windows 10. I also have Python 3.9 installed separately.
I have a few questions to go with this if that is okay.

1. With Anaconda installed, do I need to install Python? Would that be redundant?
2. Would having installed Python separately cause issues with conda or with Spyder?
3. Do I need to reinstall Anaconda?
4. Do I need to uninstall Python?
5. After having solved this problem with your help, can the method used to solve this problem (InternalArchiveError) be generalized so if I encounter it again I know what to do?

I have tried the command:
conda clean -a
which did not work and I found from here: [InvalidArchiveError when executing conda install notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657306/invalidarchiveerror-when-executing-conda-install-notebook)

This post addresses InvalidArchiveError for a different problem and the solution worked for someone using Ubuntu. I was hoping for the best in trying it for my setup.

When I do that however I am getting an internal archive error:
[The project name is enph_proj, to denote a space where I will do a small time series analysis on a stock with ticker enph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2czK.png)

Here is a picture of my 'conda info'. I hope it is helpful
[conda info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKaAd.png)

Thank you all!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to work with conda environments and connect them to Spyder.

Comment: Thanks. I also looked at a solution regarding where Anaconda is/was installed in my systems directory/C drive. I uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it for all Users and within the main level of C drive.